# ionic 2/3 : static progress bar

Tags: html, css, ionic2, progress-bar

I have a psd to integrate to ionic 3 and it contain a progress bar (see the image bellow ) and I want to ask is there a ready ionic default component to use or should I build it by html and css ? 
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not a progress bar in Ionic.
Anyway, you can use any Angular 2/4 component. I have used the [ngx-progressbar](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-progressbar) once, it works fine.

You can also check this [blog post](https://medium.com/letsboot/lets-add-a-progress-bar-to-angular-4-apps-using-ngx-progressbar-45a2a1089d4e) with more details.

Comment: Thanks @Christian , but I got this error : Cannot find the '@angular/common/http' module

Answer (score 0):

For ionic 3 with angular4 & above you could use this very easy to use plugin to show the exact percentage of upload & download. To actually get the upload & download & some other events' percentage you will of-course listen to angular reportProgess events.

npm plugin link [Angular / Ionic Progress bar component](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-progress-bar)

and read more about angular progress events:  [Listening to progress events](https://angular.io/guide/http#listening-to-progress-events)